# Addind Datepicker_plus from bootstrap but button inactive

Tags: django, bootstrap-datepicker

I add bootstrap_datepicker_plus to my code. In my template, I can see the calendar button on the right side of my field but when I click on the button nothing happened

try to modify settings, and template organization but nothing changes

Hi thanks for that. I still an issue, button on the right side to select date in the template is not working. I click on it but nothing..
this is the code modified:
in setting.py

```
# needed for using bootstrap_datepicker_plus
BOOTSTRAP3 = {
    'include_jquery': True,
}
```

and add 'bootstrap_datepicker_plus', in installed apps

html file:

```
   {%  extends 'imports/base.html' %}
{%  load bootstrap3 %}
<!-- necessaire pour date picker -->
{% block extra_css %}
{{ form.media.css }}
{% endblock %}

{% block extra_js %}
{{ form.media.js }}
{% endblock %}
<!-- Fin date picker -->
{%  block title %}Imports Company{%  endblock %}
{%  block heading %}<h3 class="page-header-center">Creation Company</h3> {%  endblock %}
<hr>
<hr>
{% block page %}
    <form method="POST">
        {%  csrf_token %}
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 content">
        {% bootstrap_form company_form %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-pink pull-right">Create</button>
        </div>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

imports/base.html:

```
{%  load staticfiles %}
{% load bootstrap3 %} {# import bootstrap4/bootstrap3 #}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
<!-- Necessaire pour bootstrap datepicker -->
{% bootstrap_css %} {# Embed Bootstrap CSS #}
{% block extra_css %}
{{ form.media.css }}
{% endblock %}
<!-- fin du code boots trap datepicker -->
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{%  static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{%  static 'css/style.css' %}">
    <script src="{%  static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 sidebar">
             {%  block sidebar %}{%  endblock %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2 content">
                {% block heading %}{% endblock %}
                {%  block page %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
    </div>

</div>


<!-- Necessaire pour bootstrap datepicker -->
{% bootstrap_javascript jquery='full' %} {# Embed Bootstrap JS+jQuery #}
{% block extra_js %}
{{ form.media.js }}
{% endblock %}
<!-- fin du code boots trap datepicker -->


</body>
</html>
```

and 
forms.py:

```
class CompanyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ("company_name", "fiscal_end_of_year")
        widgets = {
            'fiscal_end_of_year': DatePickerInput(),  # default date-format %m/%d/%Y will be used
        }
```

models.py:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    company_id = models.IntegerField(default=170)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    fiscal_end_of_year = models.DateField()
```

I missed something but where :-) ?

Expects to see calendar when clicking on the button